# moment.preciseDiff() not working properly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using momentjs precise difference to calculate the time difference between two moment objects but each time it returns 6 hours, however the difference should be less then 2 hours. Below is my code.

The first object contains US date which I converted using moment.tz('Asia/Karachi').

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWi80.png):
[image: Check this image]

Comment: Try converting both to utc before calculating the difference.

Comment: not working even, now it shows me 7 hours difference.

Comment: However its working perfectly, if i am in same timezone.